# Discord bot join/leave channel change separately per guild

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to find out how to make a command that detects a channel from separate guilds (etc. $setwelcome #channel). I have made the command but, instead of setting it for one guild its setting it for all guilds. this is my code

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
console.log("New member joined.");

console.log(`Matching on joinChannel: ${joinChannel}`);
const channelID = joinChannel.toString().match(/\d+/)[0];
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);
console.log(`Fetched channel with ${channelID}`);



// Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
if (!channel){
  console.log("The joinChannel does not exist.");
}else{
  // Send the message, mentioning the member
  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);
  member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.name === 'member'));
}
});
/*const channel = member.guild.channels.cach.find((ch) => {
console.log(ch.name);
return ch.name === joinChannel;*/

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member =>{

console.log(`Matching on joinChannel: ${joinChannel}`);
const channelID = joinChannel.toString().match(/\d+/)[0];
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);
console.log(`Fetched channel with ${channelID}`);
// Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
if (!channel) return;
// Send the message, mentioning the member
channel.send(`Goodbye ${member}, we will miss you :cry:`);
})

client.on("message", message => {
if (!message.author.bot){
    const content = message.content;
    if (content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}setwelcome`)){
        joinChannel = content.substring((`${prefix}setwelcome`).length).trim();
        console.log(`Join channel changed to ${joinChannel}`);
    }
 }
 });
```

Comment: You could use an array or object to store the guild relative to the  channel ID, but such a cache would reset upon starting your bot.  Your best case is using a database and query it to find the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use JSON, best in a database, or different file:

```js
//how the JSON should look like
{
"G123456789012345678": "123456789012345678"
}
//first part is the guild ID, second, is the id the channel you choose
```

Now you have to somehow modify this data, for this I will use fs, which assumes that this is in the file system. I’ll reference it as if it was in the same folder, and is named: welcomeChannels.json

```js
const fs = require('fs');
//maybe other "requires"
client.on('message', msg => {
//checking message content etc
let ChansString = fs.readFileSync('./welcomeChannels.json');
let chans = JSON.parse(ChansString);
//you can get the channel for the guild with chans['G'+guild.id]
chans['G'+msg.guild.id] = msg.mentions.channels.first().id || msg.channel.id;
fs.writeFileSync('./welcomeChannels.json', JSON.stringify(chans));
})
//use chans[`G${guild.id}`] to get the welcome channel id
```

Warning: this could fill up your storage. You should use a database instead.

Comment: ok, but how do I get the id from out of the json file for each server

Comment: It says there `chans['G'+guild.id]`

Comment: for the chans guild thing, it did not add another id to the json file

Comment: and if i were to add a database, how would that work?

Comment: I edited something, make sure it’s not guild.id, make it msg.guild.id

Comment: The database would work basically like that, but instead of fs, you use the database module instead.

Comment: i got an error from the `msg.mentions.channels.first().id` it says ``chans['G'+msg.guild.id] = msg.mentions.channels.first().id || msg.channel.id;
                                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at Client.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:399:56)``

Comment: Ohh are you mentioning a channel?

Comment: Well channels.first() returns undefined, so look at that. I don’t really know